Catching Exceptions inside androidx.paging.PagingData transformation methods
I have a method, where I am transforming the paging data models into UIModels.
  pagingData
    .map { cachedData ->
      deserialize(cachedData)
    }
    .filter {
       it.isSuccess
    }
    .map { it ->
       mapToUiModel(it.getOrThrow())
    }

The code has 2 potential breaking points, 1st when deserialize happens, 2nd when getOrThrow() happens.
If I put a .catch { } at the end of it, it's not catching, because the PagingData transformations are happening on another thread, if I put try catch, not catching either.
Any advice?
Thanks,

Your deserialize returns a Result which, I assume, encapsulates any errors occurred during deserialization. Then you filter out all the failed Results, which means getOrThrow will never actually throw.
So, if you want to handle the deserialization errors, you just need to analyze the Results before filtering.
  pagingData
    .map { cachedData ->
      deserialize(cachedData)
    }
    .filter {
       it.exceptionOrNull()?.let { e ->
           println("Deserialize error $e")
       }
       it.isSuccess
    }
    .map { it ->
       mapToUiModel(it.getOrThrow())
    }


Thanks! I like the part to check for exceptions inside the filter.
PageData dose not offer onEach method.
